# What is mentioned inside the parameters of SciSpark netcdf file using scala?

Tags: scala

```
val sRDD = sc.NetcdfFile(inputFile, List(variable), partCount)
```

List(variable)

means what ? and how we can read the data as `rdd[String]`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a look at what's happening in
[NetcdfFile()](https://github.com/SciSpark/SciSpark/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/dia/core/SciSparkContext.scala#L74-L90)

NetcdfFile  constructs an SRDD from a file of URI's pointing to NetCDF datasets and a list of variable names. If no names are provided then all variable arrays in the file are loaded. The URI could be an OpenDapURL or a filesystem path.

So to answer your question - List(variable) is just a list of one netcdf variable. You can put more in the list, to extract more variables from each netcdf file.

You can use wholeTextFiles() which is a function in the original SparkContext implemented in Spark to read the entire netcdf file as a string. The goal behind sRDD and the underlying sciTensor is to read in only what is needed from the netcdf file and store the data as n-dimensional arrays.

I also recommend looking at NetcdfDFSFile() which is easier to use since you do not have to create a list of path names. You can list the HDFS or local path to read from and it will load all the files from that location.